# Доступ из Python к Firebird

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebird

Как создать в python базу данных firebird и записать в нее данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python Driver](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/python-driver/).

В качестве примера [Скрипт для резервирования базы данных на Python](http://www.firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=skript_dlja_rezervirovanija_bazy_dannyx_na_python).